# MySQL Trigger ERROR in phpAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

Hi
Is there any error in this TRIGGER Statement.When ever i try to run this in phpAdmin its giving error saying "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near "SELECT Count(*) into SIM_CCode_Count".I cant get what's wrong in this..please help me

This is my trigger statement

```
CREATE TRIGGER Is_CountryCode_There After INSERT on mr_details FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN 

DECLARE SIM_CCode_Count INTEGER;
DECLARE NET_CCode_Count INTEGER;


SELECT Count(*) into SIM_CCode_Count FROM Country_Main where CountryCode=NEW.SimCntISO;

IF SIM_CCode_Count=0 THEN
INSERT INTO Country_Main(CountryCode,CountryName) Values(NEW.SIMCntISO,"Unknown");
END IF

If NEW.SimCntISO<>NEW.NetCntISO then

SELECT Count(*) into NET_CCode_Count FROM Country_Main
where CountryCode=NEW.NetCntISO

IF NET_CCode_Count=0 THEN
INSERT INTO Country_Main(CountryCode,CountryName) Values(NEW.NETCntISO,"Unknown");
END IF


END IF
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without proper explanation about your requirement and about tables and what you are expecting this trigger to do,its very difficult to say if any issues there in your trigger..
But as far as i can see there is some minor correction need to be done..
Try this Code and let know in detail your requirements..

```
CREATE TRIGGER Is_CountryCode_There After INSERT on mr_details FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE SIM_CCode_Count INTEGER;
DECLARE NET_CCode_Count INTEGER;

SELECT Count(*) into SIM_CCode_Count FROM Country_Main where CountryCode=NEW.SimCntISO;

IF SIM_CCode_Count=0 THEN
INSERT INTO Country_Main(CountryCode,CountryName) Values(NEW.SIMCntISO,"Unknown");
END IF;

If (NEW.SimCntISO<>NEW.NetCntISO) then
SELECT Count(*) into NET_CCode_Count FROM Country_Main
where CountryCode=NEW.NetCntISO;

IF NET_CCode_Count=0 THEN
INSERT INTO Country_Main(CountryCode,CountryName) Values(NEW.NETCntISO,"Unknown");
END IF;


End IF;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply..but still its showing "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3 "

Comment: hmm.. Try giving // in the delimiter Textbox of SQL tab in phpadmin along with the above code

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a mysql-statement delimiter before the trigger statement:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER ...
    (your code)
END|

DELIMITER ;
```

Otherwise MySQL interprets your `;` in this statement as statement commit and executes the code immidiately. With the delimiter changed to a different character you can use the semicolon inside the trigger declaration safely.

See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html